# Ignore first three lines & ignore lines with marks

Tags: bash, git, line, diff, ignore

In git bash

- How to ignore the first three lines during git diff between the working directory and repo?
- How to ignore any differences for all lines begin with an exclamation mark!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hunt up [text conversion for diffing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+diff+textconv), you can preprocess anything before diff looks at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the relevant commands:

`git diff | tail -n +3 | grep -v "^!"`

Answer (score 1):

The [Chris_Rands solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782024/2900196) is a good fit. But just for fun, here's a `bash` only solution:

```
i=0; git diff|while read -r; do [[ $i -gt 3 && ! $REPLY =~ ^\! ]] && echo $REPLY; (( i++ )); done
```

Or without piping and opening a subshell:

```
i=0; while read -r; do [[ $i -gt 3 && ! $REPLY =~ ^\! ]] && echo $REPLY; (( i++ )); done < <(git diff)
```

You can also use `awk` instead of bash:

```
git diff | awk 'BEGIN {i=0} {if(i > 3 && !($0 ~ "^!")) {print $0}; i++}
```

And finally my favorite in this case, using `sed`:

```
git diff | sed "1,3d;/^\!.*/d"
```

Personally I'd go with this last one.

Comment: Many thanks, Mr. Idriss Neumann &  Mr.Chris_Rands for your cooperation.
The issue faced when ignored lines with exclamation marks is when the two lines compared begin with ! the comparison ignored as needed for example 
- !ip address 192.168.1.1
+ !ip address 192.168.10.11
In the above scenario, the comparison ignored as a request; but when one of the lines started with ! removed or new line added with !, the comparison not ignored, e.g
- !ip address 192.168.1.1
+ ip address 192.168.10.11
Is it possible to ignore and combine the two cases mentioned here in one git diff command?

Comment: You can try to use sed in this case. For example : `git diff | sed "1,3d;/^\!.*/,+1d"` will remove the lines that start with `!` and the line next each match.

Comment: Once executed the sed command mentioed nothing has been changed. All differences have been appeared including !